# Under condition lock in Java web application

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, concurrency, locking

I have a function in my java web application that needs a special care. I have used Synchronize for that. But this decreased the performance of my application. The function has only one input argument and the challenge is that to lock it only if another thread is calling it by the same input value. 
Can you help me on this situation please? I don't know what is the best idea and method to use for this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Update: The code is something like this

```
String userInput = request.getParameterValues("Input");
synchronized (this){
    try{
        msg2display = myFunction(userInput);
    }
    catch(myException e) {
        msg2dispaly = e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: hmmm question : why are you calling the function with the same input from multiple threads ? for example if the input is `String` you can create a thread per unique string thus no two threads will call the function with the same input

Comment: Instead of synchronizing the method, synchronize on the shared data being accessed (those that create the need for mutual exclusion in the first place) or something representative of them.  If you want a detailed suggestion, post actual code.

Comment: How can I synchronize on the shared data?

Comment: Show the code for `myFunction`. Why does it need to be single threaded?